# stop gnome from hiding the taskbar and sidebar in fullscreen mode

Tags: gnome, fullscreen, taskbar

Is there an option which enables that fullscreen apps only are able to overdraw the taskbar and titlebar, but then stop the hiding of it. There are two advatages:

- When you are in a game and you alt+Tab out of it, it doesn't look weird, because the Titlebar taske a bit to load
- When you use telegram and you view an image it looks like this, because it only adds a semi transparent layer to darken the environment:

[image]